# React - dynamic index of array. Giving undefined for object key

Tags: reactjs

I have a component that is collecting an array of objects from .json

```
function DisplaySingleQuestion() {
    const [ displaySingleQuestion, setDisplaySingleQuestion ] = useState([]);
    const [ questionNumber, setQuestionNumber ] = useState(0);
    const [currentQuestion, setCurrentQuestion ] = useState("");

    useEffect(() => {
        fetch("./database/questions.json").then(
            async resp => await resp.json()
        ).then(
            data => setDisplaySingleQuestion(data.questions)
        )
        .catch(
            err => console.log(err)
        )
    }, []);

    useEffect(() => {
        setCurrentQuestion(displaySingleQuestion[questionNumber])
    }, [displaySingleQuestion]);

    console.log(currentQuestion.question);


    return (
    <div>
        <p>to jest Single Question</p>

        <div style={{backgroundColor: "red"}}>
                {/* <p>{displaySingleQuestion[questionNumber].question}</p> */}
        </div>
    </div>
    )
}
```

If I ask for a specific array index it works well.
For example: `displaySingleQuestion[0].question` shows the right string.
If instead I get the `0` from the state, it gives undefined.

The component above gives undefined on `console.log(currentQuestion.question);`
However if I run `console.log(currentQuestion);` it shows the object in question:

```
{id: 1, question: "Question text?"}
id: 1question: "Question text?"
[[Prototype]]: Object
```

The JSON looks like this:

```
{
    "questions": [ 
    {
        "id": 1,
        "question": "Question text?"
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "question": "Banan??"
    },
    {
        "id": 3,
        "question": "Cytryna?"
    },
    {
        "id": 4,
        "question": "Dynia?"
    },
    {
        "id": 5,
        "question": "Eukaliptus?"
    }

    ]
}
```

Why can't I select the `question` key by calling `displaySingleQuestion[questionNumber].question`?

What am I doing wrong, and how to fix it?

Thank you

Comment: Can you check the what is the type of `data.questions` is it an array or object ?

Comment: it is an array (I just just put in the original question the JSON part)